# Change the component type dynamically

Tags: extjs

I have a date field component in EXTJS 4.2 which needs to be converted to textfield at runtime based on a certain condition.

```
DATMETTEUR = Ext.create( 'Ext.form.field.Date', {
        name: 'DATMETTEUR',
        id: '${DBName}.${TableName}.DATMETTEUR',        
        format: 'd/m/Y',
        maxValue:new Date(),
        labelWidth: 108,
        labelPad: 0,
        fieldLabel: "${tr.DATMETTEUR}"
});
```

Should i convert it or hide it and replace it with the second component in the form

Comment: Do you want to do this with a particular reason? I mean, it's because you want that the users can't type anymore on the datefield based on your condition? If that's the case, you can use the property `readOnly` or `editable`

Comment: no what i want is : in mode search the user can search for records between two dates , so he wants to write like that : 05/19/2015 : 08/19/2015 (textfield is needed). As for the insert mode i want a datefield with a specific format.

Comment: Ok, i get want you want. I think that you can't reconvert components in runtime (i'm not 100% sure about this). What you can do is create two components (datefield and textfield) and use the property `hidden:true` or `hidden:false` to see just one of them depending on your condition.

Comment: Thank you , this is the solution i took